# Physics Bodies/ Sprites Changing Position For No Reason

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, position, sprite, skphysicsbody

I have several sprite physics bodies lined up next to one another, each physics body should be just slightly touching the next physics body. When I leave the app in idle for a few minutes, some of the physics bodies start to over lap each other, and when I leave the app in idle for hours, the physics body are significantly overlapping each other (about 5-10 pixels). *It could be that the sprites are moving, not the physics bodies, I can really tell which one.*

I don't think that collisions between the physics bodies is pushing the position around, as I setup each physics body's collisionBitMask so that they do not collide with one another. Also, there is currently no SKActions in place to move anything in the app.

Below is the code I use to setup each physics body:

```
spriteSegment = SKSpriteNode(texture: arrayTextureSegments[segmentType])
spriteSegment.position.x = CGFloat(countSegment) * 30 // the spriteSegment size is 30 by the way

spriteSegment.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: spriteSegment.size)
spriteSegment.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
spriteSegment.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
spriteSegment.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

spriteSegment.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bitType1
spriteSegment.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = bitType2
spriteSegment.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bitType2

addChild(spriteSegment)
```

Does anybody know what would be creating this behaviour?

**EDIT:**

Done up a sample and I still get the same strange behaviour where the images change position. I notice a small change at 20 mins, but if the app is left in idle for a hour, you should be able to clearly see what I'm talking about.

GameScene.swift code:
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3496

GameViewController.swift code:
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3497

Segment Image (0@2x~iphone.png):

[image]

**Edit:**

Here is an image of the difference before and after an hour. The blueish color is the physics body outline.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Don't know if I've done this right, but link for entire project: [click here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8x3ig67kvmaarl8/AAArzXfI1yPac_QfW20xjW1Ya?dl=0)

**Last Edit:**

I recorded where each sprite was every 20 mins, here are the results.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue over overlapping using your code. Can you make a sample project and upload it somewhere? That will be helpful to find the real problem.

Comment: Sure, I've now done up a sample, but before I upload it, I'm going to test it to make sure it creates the same problem.

Comment: Include your texture 'Segment' as well

Comment: And what's the yellow part? I suggest you upload the whole project to github or dropbox.

Comment: The yellow part is just a random sprite that was part of the original project, but is not included in the sample (I had these screen shot already saved, thats why I used them). The code for the entire sample is in the two links provided and I have now attached the segment I used for the sample.

I'll give github a go now.

Comment: Nothing happened after 1 hour here.

Comment: Really? I was just about to post some results of the sprite moves, I had 1 sprite move 19 px over 1 hour.

Comment: And the Sample project you pasted at the end is still missing the Segment.atlas. Have you copy the file or just add its reference?

Comment: I havn't had the chance to test this on my device, but I will do that next. Did you test yours on a device or simulator? Also, are you running iOS 9?

Comment: I tested it on iPad running on iOS 8. How do you record the sprite's position?

Comment: spritePlatform.enumerateChildNodesWithName("*"), this wasn't part of the sample, I only added this a hour ago for testing. And sorry the segment.atlas would have been a reference not a copy. I'm thinking this might be an iOS 9 problem then, I'll test the app on my phone, but I'll probably get the same behaviour as it is running iOS 9 as well, but time will tell.

Comment: Yes, sprites 'moved' in my Xcode 7 simulator.

Comment: What does `spritePlatform` do? It is off screen.

Comment: Just checked my phone, which is run iOS 9. And no sprites moved. Must be isolated to the simulator, wish I had of checked my phone first. I can live with the simulator not working correctly. Thanks a lot Wang for your time testing this issue out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The platform will eventually move and carry the sprites along with it, but I hadn't implemented that yet.